# Using Elasticsearch ingest attachment plugin on Angular 2 app

Tags: angular, typescript, elasticsearch, routes, single-page-application

I'm trying to use some Elasticsearch characteristics in an Angular 2 app, like uploading PDF files to extract their data and add it to an Elasticsearch service. I'm using the Elasticsearch NPM package and it works ok when I try to create an index and add documents to it, but I want to use the ingest-attachment plugin to add the file contents to my service.

So the code to add a document to an index is like this:

```
this.elastic.addToIndex({
        index: "testdocs",
        type: 'doc',
        id: this.id,
        body: {
          data : datos
        }
      }).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        alert('Success');
        this.id = this.id + 1;
      }, error => {
        alert('Fail :)');
        console.error(error);
      });
```

But how do I make the first put query of the ingest process where I have to add the information to the pipeline? I tried to do something like this:

```
this.elastic.addToIndex({
      index: "_ingest",
      type: 'pipeline',
      id: "attachment",
      body: {
        description : "Tipo " + this.file.type + " | " + this.file.name,
        processors : [
        {
          attachment : {
            field : "data",
            properties : [ "content", "title", "name", "author", "keywords", "date", "content_type", "content_length", "language"]
          }
        }
      ]
      }
```

[...]

But all I get is a 400 error like this:

```
"type": "invalid_index_name_exception",
      "reason": "Invalid index name [_ingest], must not start with \u0027_\u0027, \u0027-\u0027, or \u0027+\u0027",
      "index_uuid": "_na_",
      "index": "_ingest"
```

Is there any way to use this ingest plugin in Angular 2? 
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: First of all, your index name cannot start with an underscore _

Comment: @cmac I know, but according to the theory I need to make a PUT request to /_ingest/pipeline/attachment first